# How do I vertically align items in a flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box containing a row of items:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">abc</div>
  <div class="text">abc</div>
</div>
```

```
.box { height: 50px; }
```

The first item is a box [] and the other items are text.

The box is bigger than the text and the text doesn't line up vertically with the middle of the box. How do I make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items: center;` should do it.

```css
/*the important stuff: */

.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  height: 50px;
  /*the following for visual only*/
  background: red;
  width: 25px;
}

.text {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="text">abc</div>
  <div class="text">abc</div>
</div>
```